# How to use asset catalog for navigation bar background image?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, asset-catalog

I use asset catalog with `2x` images for iPhone5 and 6 as described in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html):

[image]

Image for navigation bar background is 750x128 (750 x 44 * 2 + 20 * 2) because I want also to cover status bar. 750 is iPhone6 resolution width. Bg image setting:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    .setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "nav_bar_bg"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Let's look at result:

[image]

OK. iPhone5:

[image]

Not OK. How can I downscale it without removing background image from asset catalog? I really don't want to hardcode it. It's really annoying that iPhone5 and 6 resources can't be separated.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, didn't notice the UINavigationBar thing... You can change the resize of the picture that is used in the background by making your picture [stretchable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html). That way you can use a picture that fits the smaller devices (the iPhone5 in your example) and keep the picture centered in the iPhone 6.

Another more convoluted solution would be to subclass the NavBar altogether and rewrite the way the picture is drawn.

---

You should use NSLayoutConstraints (leading, top and trailing), and set the UIImageView content to Fit. That way you won't need to change the image, it will be automatically scaled by the application.

Comment: Does `UINavigationBar` provide api for retrieving bg image view?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Updated my answer with a `possible` solution.

Comment: Thanks, best catch in my opinion is NavBar subclass